# Problem with the session in the asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, session

I'm new to the asp.net. I'm developing one web site which is having diffenent web pages &

I've created 3 web pages in all web pages i set the one session variable & depending on that session variable i'm performing the different operation. Problem which is i'm facing is that when i open my 1st page then that session variable is empty & it works as i want but when i open my 2nd page that time session variable get's value & that page also works fine. But when i back to my first page then the session variable having the value & which i don't want. And if i clear the session variable then i'm failed to work with my 3rd page which work on the session value.

I'm unable to explain my whole problem in right manner but if anyone having soluntion on this problem then please reply to this question?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It you dont want to use the session variable on the first page and want to use that variable value on the page 2 and 3.

solution 1 is make use of the viewstate or querystring on the page 2 and 3.

Solution 2 is make use of one more flag variable which indicate the seesion varialbe now has the value and based on that you can perform activity when you go back to page 1 from page 2.

Comment: I'm agree with you. But i'm having one web page which will be called from different pages & i want to show the required menu on that page depending on the session variable value then what should i do in this situation?

Comment: @Priyanka - there simple solution is do check that session vaiable has value or not.........thats it

Comment: when i set the session variable value on particular page  then onwards it is having value. Then how can i check Whether session having value or not?

Comment: @Priyanka - as i get your question you dont need session variable on the first page and in page 2 and 3 you need it , so its better you skip the session varible form the first page

Comment: @Priyanka = as you said on the page 1 you dont need the seesion variable and it null in first hit , so when you hit it second time you get the value of session variable so just check if(Session["value"]==null) or not thats it and if not null then do the work accordingly............